# Simple Python Web Server Responds to cURL and Epiphany, Not Firefox

Tags: python, sockets, firefox

I am implementing a SIMPLE web server in Python 3 for learning purposes. Currently, all I am trying to get the server to do is receive (and eventually parse) an HTTP request. The code is as follows:

```
from socket import *
import sys

serverName = getfqdn(gethostname())
serverPort = 13544

# prepare serverSocket for listening
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)
print('The server is ready to recieve on {}:{}.'.format(serverName, serverPort))

# handle requests
while True:
    connectionSocket, address = serverSocket.accept()
    print('Accepted a connection from {}:{}.'.format(address[0], address[1]))
    message = connectionSocket.recv(2048).decode()
    print('Recieved a message from {}:{}:'.format(address[0], address[1]))
    message = message.split('\n')
    for line in message:
        if not line == '' and not line[0] == ' ':
            print('  ' + line)
```

Using "curl localhost:13544" yields output on the server terminal. Navigating to "localhost:13544" in Epiphany yields output on the server terminal. However, navigating to "localhost:13544" in Firefox yields no output. Firefox simply reports that a connection to the host could not be established. Any ideas what the difference could be?

Comment: Have you tried using your hostname in FF? Or IP address?

Comment: @Maelstrom, I have tried using my hostname, 127.0.0.1, and localhost.

Comment: What error did you get on FF? For me (Ubuntu) I am able to connect fine (FF is waiting/spinning) and I got messages on the terminal where the code is running.
Did you check your network settings in FF? Is there proxy?